# Pending Balance Doesn't Payout to Miner

Tags: go-ethereum, mining-pools

I was mining on my own pool with open-ethereum-pool.
Now I had mined and I have Pending Balance on my account there.

How can I payout it? When I make `./build/bin/open-ethereum-pool payout.json` which has the payout config from `config.json`

It says `No payees that have reached payout threshold`

But I don't know why. Minimum Payout is 0.5 and I have 10.0 in the account. So the minimum is reached.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just mining to your own wallet (as I'm guessing you'd have set for your pool's address), the ether should already be accessible without enabling payouts (thus saving you transaction fees).

If you want to use the payout module, https://github.com/sammy007/open-ethereum-pool/blob/master/docs/PAYOUTS.md suggests you need to set the `RESOLVE_PAYOUT` environment variable. You should also check your configuration file; I believe you need to have the `unlocker` module enabled, in addition to the `payouts` module. Lastly, you might want to check on a site like http://etherscan.io that you actually mined the blocks your pool says you mined.

... okay, lastly-lastly, make sure your miners are being credited for work done; you can do this via the GUI and/or via `redis`.

Comment: Thanks for answering lungj!

Geth has an own Wallet Address. Only for the Pool. The Pool is for me and friends. So i want to payout them.

I also checked this link. I have unlocker.json and payouts.json running. Both of them "works". I already have pending balance on my account (website) but it is not paying out. Only pending...

I also tried `RESOLVE_PAYOUT=1 ./build/bin/open-ethereum-pool payouts.json` but also nothing :( he doesnt payout "pending balance" but why?! open-ethereum-pool also closed issues, so cannot ask there :/

On geth i see that my wallet have the coins

Comment: Just checking: when you say "Minimum Payout is 0.5 and i have 10.0 on account", do you mean that the account you're expecting to have a payout is 10.0? Or do you mean that the whole pool is 10.0? The minimum payout is per Ethereum address/account.